# Installed Tor, it wont open

Tags: configuration

Says it cant reach port. I was never offered the option to configure it (Region allowed, not allowed) and have disabled and reconfigured windows defender several times. I double checked that my clock was synced. The only error is "could not connect to Tor control port" which leads me to think firewall. Any ideas ?

Comment: the log could probably help us to help you... ;-)

Comment: user@user's-desktop:~$ cd tor-browser_en-US
user@user's-desktop:~/tor-browser_en-US$ ./start-tor-browser.desktop
/usr/bin/env: ./Browser/execdesktop: Permission